# Dictionary parameter in ODATA action in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata

Is there a way to pass a collection parameter of Dictionary type to an ODATA action? The JSON payload will look like this:

```
{
    "MyParameter": [
         {
              "property1": "A",
              "property2": "B"
         },
         {
              "otherProperty": 1,
              "property2": "C"
         }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first define a parameters class

```
public class MyActionParameters
{
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> MyParameter
    {
    }
}
```

and then in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyAction")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Sync([FromBody] MyActionParameters parameters)
{
}
```